# Invalid Operation trying to insert values in to Access Database

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have this code below and when I try to run it, it crashes with the error message, "Invalid Operation" on the last line in the code.  All the Syntax looks correct.  What am I doing wrong?

```
PCycle = PreviousCycle(CurrentCycle(Me.cobMainType.Value), mainType(Me.cobMainType.Value))

SQL = "INSERT INTO tblVehMainType (MainID, PartID, VehTypeID)"
SQL = SQL & " Select " & Me.cobMainType & ", PartID, VehTypeID"
SQL = SQL & " From tblVehMainType "
SQL = SQL & " WHERE vehTypeID = " & Me.cobVehType & " AND MainID = " & PCycle & ";"

Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(SQL)
```

Answer (score 2):

An `INSERT` statement does not return a recordset so you should not use `.OpenRecordset` to run it. You should use `.Execute` instead.